# need clarification on BODMAS rule

Tags: java, c++, c, math

In BODMAS rule the order of operations are brackets,order,division,multiplication addition and subtraction.here division,multiplication,addition and subtraction is following decrement,increment ,increment and decrement order.the BODMAS rule series is not following the same order.And my question is why addition is followed by subtraction but not subtraction is followed by addition.

Comment: Because BOMDSA would be harder to pronounce?

Comment: I was taught it's BOMDAS

Comment: I m not convinced but thanks.

Comment: This question is better suited for [mathematics.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Jittu check this out(http://gadgetopia.com/post/5878)

Answer (score 7):

BODMAS or BOMDSA are exactly the same, since multiplication/division and addition/subtraction are at the same level of precedence (in facts, they should be written more correctly as `B O DM AS`, with whatever order you prefer inside the various groups); as said by the relevant [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations):

> These mnemonics may be misleading when written this way, especially if the user is not aware that **multiplication and division are of equal precedence, as are addition and subtraction**.

In other words, what you are missing is that normally (both when doing math "manually" and in any sane programming language) the operators are actually grouped by *classes* of precedence, where multiplication and division have the same precedence (as well as sum and subtraction). So, your "BODMAS rule" actually is actually:

```
() 
**
* /
+ -
```

(I use `**` as the exponentiation operator - as it is in Python -, as Java does not provide one; also, () here are grouping symbols, not operators)

The precedence of operators on the same line is determined by their order in an expression and their associativity (which, for arithmetic operators, is left to right, although for exponentiation is not well defined).

Although for math on reals this is not really relevant unless talking about division (addition and subtraction are associative, if you consider subtraction as "addition of the opposite"), in programming it *is* double important, since math on FP numbers and on integers is often not associative.

Also, programming languages provide many more operators, not associative/commutative, with different associativity and not so well established precedence rules, so it's normal that they specify their rules for operators precedence in a more refined way.

See for example the [operator precedence and associativity table of Java](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~palsetia/java/precedenceTable.html): it's way more complicated than the simple "BODMAS rule", which is inadequate to correctly express it (since there are many classes, more operators in each class, classes with different associativity, ...).

Comment: Exponentiation is right-associative in mathematics, and hopefully in every programming language that has an exponentiation operator (or three). It is in Haskell and Python.

Comment: @DanielFischer: in mathematics normally there's no ambiguity because you use superscript notation; in programming languages, as you said it's normally right-associative, but in real code in case of multiple exponentiations I've almost always seen it "clarified" with parentheses, sign that its right associativity is not so intuitive.

Comment: Even with superscript notation, you can still associate two ways. (I can't show it here, but if you can read LaTeX, `$2 ^ {(3^4)}$` vs. `${\bigl( 2^3 \bigr)} ^ 4$`.) Absent explicit parentheses, `$2^{3^4}$` means the first.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, both subtraction and addition are, oddly enough, addition. Subtraction is simply the addition of a negative number.

**Eg:**

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = x - y; // Is actually x + (-y)
```

Comment: then what is the value of 6-4+2.irrespective of programming using BODMAS rule

Comment: Well look at BODMAS. 6 - 4 + 2. Add the terms first, so it's `6 - 6` which is `0`.

Comment: its not 6-4*2 but it is 6-4+2

Comment: In java its 4 its not 0

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), you will see that operators of equal presidence are evaluated from left to right. That is `6 + (-4) = 2`, `2 + 2 = 4`.

Comment: Ya I know that your also confused :). But thanks. other than  programing I am asking in mathematical terms why BODMAS rule why not BODMSA

Comment: I'm not confused at all. Java parses it's equations using the left to right rule for operators of equal precedence. And.. I don't know. But [this answer](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071120030039AAthLBl) seems to be quite helpful.

Comment: whether it java or spanish BODMAS is BODMAS.

Answer (score 0):

well its just a term, in mathematics, it give same result if you + then - or - then +, so is for * and /.

```
(x - y) = (-y + x) And (x*y)/z = x*(y/z) And x-y*z = x-(y*z) = -(y*z)+x
```

Just only thing matter is, you must have calculate *,/ before +,- corresponding to the bracket they are in.

Comment: then what is the value of 6-4+2.irrespective of programming using BODMAS rule We are getting two results 6-4+2=0 and other is 4

Comment: look at the sign on numbers, its -4 & +2 its not -(+4, +2)

Comment: can you elobrate please

Comment: the result is based on sign on numbers, since we have bracket to group operation, it gives different meaning altogether -4 + 2 is as simple as it looks, but -(4 + 2) equals -4 -2 because the - is on the result not on individual number

Comment: my question is not about operator precedence but about its order ,please refer the question once

Comment: @Jittu how are you getting 0 for 6-4+2?

Comment: BODMAS IS an operator precedence rule, there in nothing like order in calculation, results are based on operator precedence only.

Comment: Ya + and - having same preference then y not its - and +

Comment: as i explained, reread the quoted part in answer. both are same, unless there is no bracket.

Comment: @Koushik 6-4+2 = 6- (4+2) = 6-6 = 0

Comment: @Jittu you have completely missed the point. how did you come up with `6-(4+2)` for`6-4+2`? it should be `6+(-4+2) if at all you want to introduce parantheses`